# CakePHP grouping if row contains the same value

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php
$user_first = "123";

$query = $this->Post->find("all", array("conditions"=>array("userid"=>$user_first, "type"=>"message"), "group"=>"date"));
foreach($query as $val){
   echo $val["message"];
   echo $val["date"];
}
?>
<div>
 //Using foreach the results would be like this:
Jan 10 2012 Hello
Jan 10 2012 Hi
Jan 10 2012 Hey
Jan 10 2012 Yo!
Jan 12 2012 Nice

But I would want to achieve is this: 
Jan 10 2012 
  Hello
  Hi
  Hey
  Yo!

Jan 12 2012
  Nice
</div>
```

I want to group the results using date. So that the if the dates have the same result, they dont have to be redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$newDate =null;
foreach($query as $val) {
    if ($newDate !== $val["date"]) {
        echo $val["date"]. "<br />";
    }

    echo $val["message"];
    $newDate = $val["date"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cast/Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the values to a Date type for your group by.

```
GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```